# MediaPlayer make 1 lag after start

Tags: android, audio, stream, android-mediaplayer

I create MediaPlayer object for playing a stream audio, from http url source. 
Every time when object starts to play audio after 3-4 seconds audio has stopped, buffering and play again, but only 1 time. Than all is good

Code :

```
String url = "http://icecast.vgtrk.cdnvideo.ru/vestifm_mp3_192kbps"; 
        audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        audioPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
            }
        });
        try {
            //setProgressBarPlayer(Constants.ACTION_BUFFERING);
            audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            audioPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            audioPlayer.prepareAsync();
            audioPlayer.setWakeMode(ctx, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my LogCat is showed below

1. W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (703, 0)
2. W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (701, 0)
3. D/audio_hw_primary﹕ disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
4. D/audio_hw_primary﹕ disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
   V/ConfigFetchTask﹕ ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1  ...
5. I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
6. W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (703, 0)
7. I/NuPlayer﹕ buffer ready, resuming...
8. W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (702, 0)

Comment: Have you solved this issue with player,because I am having same issue if yes please help